# Building a video wall with devices

Tags: video, multiple-monitors

I am entertaining building a video wall made out of many android devices. But I have to say I have no clue about how to go about it? The fact that these are android devices is not very important I am curious about the general approach to doing video walls with many separated devices.
At best the desktop of one machine should be displayed on all the devices. If not I would be also interested in just showing just a video on that wall.

Comment: I believe I've heard of MythTV being used this way, some how. Personally, after much googling, I suspect I'd settle in to writing a video output plugin/driver for mplayer and adapt that to your needs. That is a fairly non-trivial problem.

Comment: This comment will not help in any way, but I wanted to brag that I work at the university with [the highest resolution tiled display in the world](http://services.tacc.utexas.edu/index.php/stallion-user-guide).

Comment: @the-white-phoenix - i agree that's seems a bit heavy duty, @william very nice :)